# Modify pages widget and make a plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, widgets, pages

I would like to make a plug-in that adds a widget. I would like it to be based on the current pages widget but add the ability to select either include OR exclude by drop down or checkbox then list pages by ID.

Following [this](http://www.question-defense.com/2009/04/09/modify-the-wordpress-pages-widget-to-include-pages-instead-of-exclude-pages) guide I was able to change the exclude to include by hacking the core file located in wp-includes/default_widgets.php.

Here is the original code:

http://pastebin.com/Rg2vTMmK

How do I make the changes and turn it into a plugin?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are class based, so it is quite easy to extend them.

1. Create your class by extending `WP_Widget_Pages` (just like it extends baseline `Widget`).
2. Copy method(s) you want to modify into your class and make changes in there. You would probably want to extend and modify name and such so it is not confused/conflicted with native widget.
3. Register your class using [`register_widget()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget).

Comment: That is a great start, I googled "extends WP_Widget_Pages" and only found https://gist.github.com/967910 which is a start, but its not a plugin....Then I found this [guide](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28) Not sure how to do it....

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-reloaded/

Comment: I would recommend that one, but you worded your question as plugin development issue, not plugin recommendation. Please mention that existing plugin would be viable answer if so when asking.